# Display Bluetooth devices (Not BLE devices) in a UITableView

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I would like to ask you one question regarding the Standard Bluetooth. I have to show list of Bluetooth devices (Not BLE devices) in a UITableView (not connected devices list). I have searched a lot regarding it,but no luck.Any ideas, suggestions could be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Use *ExternalAccessory.framework*.
You can get the list with:

```
NSArray* accessoryList = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

The use this array to display it in a *UITableView*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also want to show not connected devices.