# How to print out a list of currently connected bluetooth accessories in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, bluetooth

For an application I'm working on we are trying to log whether an iDevice is using an external GPS accessory such as the xgps.  I've become a little confused exactly how to do this.

I understand there is a `(NSArray *)retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs` call which might help but I'm unsure what to use for the `serviceUUIDs` and I couldn't really find much from the documentation.  I understand I'm looking for **A list of service UUIDs (represented by CBUUID objects).**

Is there some sort of standardized list in the bluetooth Spec I should be using?  I didn't see anything listing GPS here: http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/doc/assigned_numbers_-_service_discovery.html

So in Summary:

In iOS 7 is there an easy way to query for connected bluetotooth devices and get information on them and if so could somebody provide a code sample?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want "Classical Bluetooth" accessories and not Bluetooth Low-Energy ones. If that's so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451647/display-bluetooth-devices-not-ble-devices-in-a-uitableview/21451903#21451903

Comment: Much Gracias!  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 /* Store all the Bluetooth accessories currently connected */
            NSArray *accessoryList = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];

            for (EAAccessory *acc in accessoryList) {

// here you can do all your stuff by accessing acc
acc.firmwareRevision;
acc.hardwareRevision;
acc.manufacturer;
acc.modelNumber;
acc.serialNumber;
acc.name;
//etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Larme pointed me to the link here: [Display Bluetooth devices (Not BLE devices) in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451647/display-bluetooth-devices-not-ble-devices-in-a-uitableview/21451903#21451903)

which specifies a call to:

```
    NSArray* accessoryList = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

which does the trick!